# Find the Maclaurin series of f(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the Maclaurin series of $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+x+x^2}$ and the radius of convergence of the series.

I can't solve this problem.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Start by doing a partial fractions decomposition

Comment: I'm studying Calculus and I just learned about power series and Taylor (+ Maclaurin series). I want to know how to approach solution.

Comment: @mrf: Partial fractions is a very useful general method that OP should become acquainted with, but in this case there is a much easier way.

Comment: To find the radius of convergence, you only need to look for the zeros of $1 + x + x^2$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** 
$$\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^3},\quad \frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n.$$

Comment: What about $\dfrac{1}{1 - (-x -x^2)}$?

Comment: @sidht: I think your approach would be harder to handle.

Comment: Nice one. I like it.

Comment: I already thought about that... (1+x+x^2+...)/(1+x^3+x^6+...) and?

Comment: I think I should study more

Comment: @Gagomse: $\frac{1-x}{1-x^3}=(1-x)\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}$. Hope you can complete the solution from here.

Comment: @Giraffe: Wouldn't it be simply  $$\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n (x + x^2)^n$$

Comment: @sidht: To obtain the Maclaurin series of $f$ from your series, you still have to do the binomial expansion of $(x+x^2)^n$.

Comment: What's wrong with leaving it like that?

Comment: @sidht: It is not a Maclaurin series. A Maclaurin series, say of $f$, must be of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, where $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

A grneral method:

Maclaurin series: $f(x)=f(0)+f^{'}(0)x+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n+\ldots $

Denote $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, using Leibniz's rule,
$$
(1+x+x^2)f(x)=1 \Rightarrow (1+x+x^2)f^{(n)}+{n\choose 1}(1+2x)f^{(n-1)}+{n\choose 2}\cdot2\cdot f^{(n-2)}=0
$$

Let $x=0$, we obtain
$$
f^{(n)}(0)+nf^{(n-1)}(0)+n(n-1)f^{(n-2)}(0)=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}+\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}+\frac{f^{(n-2)}(0)}{(n-2)!}=0
$$
Hence $a_n=-(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$, and $a_0=1,a_1=-1$. Now you know the Maclaurin series.